# new Jsch() no exception

Tags: java, exception, jsch

I'm ruunning this code but don't get error:

```
   JSch jsch = null ;
    try {
      logger.debug("rla new jsch");
      jsch = new JSch();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        logger.debug("rla catch: {}",e.getClass());
    }
    logger.debug("rla end new jsch");
```

Execute stop after new Jsch() but don't catch exception why ?

After catch logger.debug never execute why ?
thanks

Comment: Either you're hanging inside the constructor or you don't have debug logging turned on.

Comment: Try to catch `Throwable` or use a debugger to find the problem.

Comment: The constructor of `JSch` is empty, so it can hardly hang or throw. Use a debugger.